# redirect a single URL to another - removing the query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a single url something like this where 456 is the ID of the category and has been rewritten into a seo friendly url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/category/nameofcategory/456.htm
```

(This is done with this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/.*/([0-9]+) home/categoryview.php?id=$1   [L,QSA]
```

I need to keep this intact for all the other categories.)

I'd like to .htaccess redirect my 456 category to a specific product's url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/products/nameofproduct/123.htm
```

If add the following to the .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /category/nameofcategory/456.htm http://www.mydomain.com/products/nameofproduct/123.htm
```

then the ID is added to the url and returns another product like this.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/products/nameofproduct/123.htm?456
```

Is there a way to remove the '?456'

Comment: You almost there just append `?` in your Redirect 301 target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias` rules. Have all rules in `mod_rewrite` only.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/[^/]+/456.htm /products/nameofproduct/123.htm? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/[^/]+/([0-9]+) /home/categoryview.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```