# htaccess redirect from multiple urls to single and remove query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect urls from;

```
http://www.example.com/news/newsitem.asp?story=20130227
http://www.example.com/news/newsitem.asp?story=20148893
```

There are other urls that I don't know so want to redirect everything from news/newsitem.asp
to

```
http://www.example.com/blog
```

I am using

```
RewriteRule ^news/newsitem.asp http://www.example.com/blog [R=301,L]
```

but the result adds the query string to the end

result = `http://www.example.com/blog?story=20130227`

How do I stop the query string being appended?

I did find this post but can't seem to make it work
[redirect a single URL to another - removing the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078560/redirect-a-single-url-to-another-removing-the-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "?" at the end of your rewrite target

```
RewriteRule ^news/newsitem.asp$ http://www.example.com/blog? [R=301,L]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it will discard the original query string from url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^news/newsitem\.asp$ /blog/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

`?` in the end will strip off any pre-existing query string.

Better to escape the DOT in regex and make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.